# Как лучше двигать дорогу или Игрока в раннере?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю runner, как лучше сделать двигать дорогу или игрока, если дорогу то у меня есть два варианта объединить все объекты на дороге в один, с помощью родительского объекта и двигать одним скриптом на сцене, а можно на каждый объект включая дороги повесить свой скрипт движения, но тогда будет много Update() срабатывать. Хочу узнать, ваше мнение мне важен оптимальный вариант чтобы он не напрягал устройство.
А да и раннер не бесконечный, а по уровням!

Спасибо за ваши ответы!

Comment: не работаю с unity, но вроде логично звучит, что одного игрока проще двигать, чем все объекты, кроме игрока

Comment: Если один уровень можно проходить бесконечно долго, как сабвей серфер то однозначно нужно двигать сам уровень. Если нет то уже по ситуации. В бесконечном уровне можно попросту вылезть за пределы возможных координат.

Comment: Если двигать игрока то вам нужно постоянно сравнить перед ним новые элементы локации. И соответственно тоже передвигать точки спауна.

Comment: @tym32167 давно уже решили эту проблему путем объекта-родителя, матрица положения объекта в пространстве меняется в зависимости от положения от всех родительских объектов в иерархии.

Comment: Двигать уровень рантайм это доисторические заморочки. Сейчас даже если такое и делают, то сдвигают всю сцену раз в некий сегмент пути в целях построения дальнейшего отрезка и избавления от старого, да и то сдвигать не обязательно, если не планируешь по координате упереца в пределы float.

Comment: @Yaroslav Проблема float в том, что чем больше значение тем меньше относительная точность. Лучше уж в какой нть Int* писать, где есть гарантированная точность на всем диапазоне.